# Framework like ATG Dynamo Application Framework

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, frameworks, atg, atg-dynamo

I am a ATG developer, I am developing an application for my own venture, I know  ATG is pretty expensive. So I want to know if there is any java framework like ATG. Of if any way to use ATG DAF free of cost or with min. expense. I just want to use the basic of DAF, Nucleus(component model), Repository and dsp taglibs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't work for Oracle so I can't comment on the commercial aspects of your question. That said, the components you are referring to are available in some shape or form in other JAVA based technologies which, with your knowledge of ATG you should be able to pick up quite quickly.

For example the Nucleus provides you IOC in a similar way that Spring does. The repository layer is a precursor to Hibernate while most of the DSP tags (useful ones at least) is mimicked by JSTL.

You could also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83142/1127677) discussion elsewhere on Stackoverflow where opensource alternatives to ATG is being discussed.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Spring. Spring also provide much thing which help you to developing these your own venture. You can also use Hibernate as per repository layer.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are no exact framework like ATG dynamo, but I have found combination of Strips Framework (https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Home) and Ebean as ORM (http://ebean-orm.github.io/) to be closed in offering to ATG.

Most of the things behave in the same manner as ATG. Below are few examples

- In ATG you refer to components by path like /com/path/MyComp in stripes you refer to ActionBeans using package like com.path.MyComp and you can access all the properties using ${actionbean.myProperty} as you do in ATG
- is equivalent to droplets, only better, instead of always calling service method(which forces you to write all the code in service method) you can invoke any method you want by passing name of the method in event variable
- For pipeline they have Interceptors
- Also have a pretty awesome validation framework
- Like ATG Stripes is also very customizable

Ebean

- Ebean is also very much simple to use, it used JPA mappings